# JSdoc for js closures

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Using jsdoc version 3.6.2

I have a project with tons of jsdoc documentation written, but unfortunately jsdoc won't parse it into the format I'm expecting.

We have numerous js files that create objects and then use function closures to define methods on those objects. I would like jsdoc to pick up those methods and associate them with the given module.

```
/** @module @mymodule*/
var mymodule = {};
/** This module is my very special module */
(function() {
    var started = false;
    /**
    * @memberof module:mymodule // I have tried this, @name, @lends, etc...
    * Start the module
    */
    mymodule.start = function() {
       started = true;
    };
})();
```

It seems no matter what I do, I can't get the start method to actually show up as a documented method of the mymodule module. If I use @alias on the method, then it shows up as a global on the jsdoc index page, but that doesn't make for a very readable index page if it just dumps 10k links.

Anyone know how I can get this method to show up on the mymodule.html page?